# Reading excel sheet from same workbook using nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am new to nodejs, i wanted to know how it is possible to read different excel sheets from excel workbook(.xlsx) using nodejs.
I tried to use excel module of nodejs to read excel file, but using it i can only read the first sheet of that  workbook. please help!!
thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check this module:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/excel-multi

If you have multiple sheets in your spreadsheet,

```
parseXlsx('Spreadsheet.xlsx', '2', function(err, data) {
    if(err) throw err;
    // data is an array of arrays
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var spread_sheet = require('spread_sheet');


var row = "1,2,Jack,Pirate";

var filePath = '/home/Pranjal/Desktop/test.xlsx';

var sheetName = "Sheet1";

var from_row  = 2;

var to_row = 6;

/*
spread_sheet.addRow(row,filePath,sheetName,function(err,result){

console.log(err,result)

})
*/

/* 
spread_sheet.getRows(filePath,sheetName,from_row,to_row,function(err,result){

console.log(err,result)
*/
```

Comment: It's much more helpful if you can explain your code a bit.  Also ctrl-k will format a code block for you all at once.